# Internet Text & Ubuntu Menu Text Color variegated - hard to read

Tags: 14.04, colors, text, appearance

I'm a new user to linux/ubuntu and I have just installed the ubuntu **14.04** version.

The drop-down menu text and the internet texts appear to be orange/red and fade/mix-up randomly.  Sometimes texts '**disappear**' completely and are unable to be seen until I click/do something else with the cursor or keyboard. Nothing else is wrong with the text except for the color itself.

For example the beginning of this post starts pink/red fades to dark blue/purple back to red/orange and then starts having interspersed letters of bright yellow and ends with light green text at the right side.

Thank you for helping me out! (:

Answer (score 0):

As described here https://askubuntu.com/a/606583/448007, the problem seems not to appear by using the old UXA hardware acceleration for for the Intel graphic cards.

Edit the following section of the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file such that AccelMethod is set to "uxa" or create the file if it does not yet exist:

```
Section "Device"    
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"    
   Driver      "intel"   
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa" 
EndSection
```

Reboot or restart X.

The problem went away for me