# Fonts disappeared all of sudden

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, fonts, gui, gpu-driver

I have installed Xubuntu 16.04 on my two PCs.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

All of a sudden (or when I unlock my PC) all the fonts disappear. I am facing this issue on both of my PCs.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Edit1: Added output **sudo lspci | grep VGA**

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: Try changing the theme, or changing the font, and tell us what happens.

Comment: The GUI does not seem to be the standard Nautilus, what Ubuntu flavour are you using?

Comment: @JuanAntonio Its Xubuntu 16.04.  Downloaded from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/

Comment: Which is your graphic card? Please add the output of `sudo lspci | grep VGA` to your question.

Comment: @luchonacho added.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/606583/308164) helps?