# Red/green inverted images - green tint

Tags: 16.04, graphics, colors, color-management

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 and have recently discovered that in certain images **red and green are inverted** - red appears green and vice versa as shown here:

[image: greenish man]

This error doesn't seem to be related to a specific file type or program as it occurs quite randomly in 75% of all images and icons. OS colors don't seem to be affected at all. Videos work fine as well as image file previews.
The error even occurs when printing. The issue can be avoided in Firefox (only!) when setting the gfx.color_management.mode to 3 - other images are still manipulated.

Is there any known solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you have anything relevant in `System Settings` -> `Colour`?

Comment: In `system settings` I choose the default `color profile`, in my case ASUSTek-K54CA. Changing the profile does not affect the inverted colors at all. Advanced booting Ubuntu in rescue mode solves the problem, but as soon as I use the normal GRUB boot procedure the error remains.
Additionally another problem seems to be somehow related: OS text does not appear normal so that only certain characters are displayed especially after suspending a couple of times.

Comment: There are several questions about missing characters, like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582980/missing-letters-in-menus-and-folder-names) and others linked by it.

Comment: Thx, it seems that I got rid of this particular problem, but the inverted color issue remains.

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: I observe the same in Chromium, Firefox, Skype, and the BlueJeans conferencing client. I have to switch off my colour profile, start the respective program, and re-enable the colour profile to see correct colours. Observed with at least Ubuntu 19.04–20.04 on different laptops.