# Icons In System Settings(unity) are Missing Ubuntu Server 17.04

Tags: unity, upgrade, icons, 17.04

I just installed 17.04 server and then desktop but I have only those icons (this is not actually my setting, but it is broken the same way)

[image: 1]

I tried these command in an attempt to solve it:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But I did not manage to solve it. Can you suggest any ways to solve my problem?

i reinstalled ubuntu desktop notihng changed sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

[image: 2]

I did this also

ht t ps: / /askubu ntu.co m /a/621874/694849

but it also added only one icon. online accounts.

They are lots of still missing icons like power.

When  i write `gnome-control -center`, i t brings lots of icons but when i click for example display, console shows:

```
➜  ~ gnome-control-center

** (gnome-control-center:11997): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher gufw (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11997): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher landscape-client-settings (missing desktop file)

** (gnome-control-center:11997): WARNING **: Ignoring launcher ubuntuone-installer (missing desktop file)

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunset data, using 16.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunrise data, using 8.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunset data, using 16.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunrise data, using 8.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunset data, using 16.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunrise data, using 8.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunset data, using 16.00

(gnome-control-center:11997): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: no sunrise data, using 8.00
```

And this did nothing

```
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon gnome-control-center-unity
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'unity-control-center' instead of 'gnome-control-center-unity'
unity-control-center is already the newest version (15.04.0+17.04.20170402.6-0ubuntu1).
unity-control-center-signon is already the newest version (0.1.9+16.10.20160825-0ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-22 linux-headers-4.10.0-22-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-22-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-22-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Also this did not do anything

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo shutdown -r now
```

see

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release          
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease           
Hit:8 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x yakkety InRelease         
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:10 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty InRelease     
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease 
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89.2 kB]
Ign:15 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 InRelease
Hit:16 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 Release
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89.2 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,812 B]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,904 B]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [27.0 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.8 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [14.0 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [57.5 kB]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [58.7 kB]
Fetched 392 kB in 1s (228 kB/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-22 linux-headers-4.10.0-22-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-22-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-22-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,612 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 356900 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-desktop_1.379_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ubuntu-desktop (1.379) over (1.379) ...
Setting up ubuntu-desktop (1.379) ...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unity is already the newest version (7.5.0+17.04.20170407.1-0ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.10.0-22 linux-headers-4.10.0-22-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-22-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.10.0-22-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And i installed xubuntu and logged and settings are same. Missing icons. SO it is not about unity?

I have those enviroments:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I have a solution for this. I have been experiencing the exact same thing since upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 and none of the proposed solutions worked for me.

By looking at the .desktop file corresponding to the missing icons entries, I found this line:

`OnlyShowIn=Unity7;`

And a `unity --version` returned `unity 7.5.0`, so i thought maybe just putting

`OnlyShowIn=Unity;`

without specifying the version would work, and bingo, icons started to re-appear in the system settings menu.

Note that deleting the line also works. Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also add `GNOME;` in front of Unity since I think as of 17.10 they will be moving back to Gnome as the default desktop and things will probably be broken if you have migrated from previous versions and the upgrade doesn't automatically replace those existing files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in Linux 4.3/4.4 that causes text to corrupt or images to disappear sporadically. It may be worth it to test 4.2 and intermittently messed up text should work.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209065

[Missing letters in menus and folder names](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582980/missing-letters-in-menus-and-folder-names/606583)