# Ubuntu 19.04 Unity get blurry when running laptop continuously without restarting

Tags: unity, 19.04

When running Ubuntu 19.04 for a few days without restarting, some Unity features get blurred out.

This is how my search panel looks like.

[image]

Everything else looks good. for example Browsers and other softwares like PHPStorm all working as it should.

I know I can fix this by restarting the system. But is there any other ways to fix this issue? I'm a developer and always have many windows and programs open. It takes a long time to reopen everything I need once the computer is restarted.

Comment: Have you installed any new themes or fonts or GNOME extensions? Edit your question with the results of `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`... not in the comments please.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/582980/missing-letters-in-menus-and-folder-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the update to 19.04, some GNOME extensions that you were running before, may not be compatible with 19.04.

Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, and then restart GNOME shell with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>, then <kbd>r</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>, and see if the problem is gone after running a while. If so, re-enable one extension at a time, restart GNOME shell, and retest. If the problem returns, you've found the bad extension.

Comment: Perfect. I just restarted Gnome with your command. It solved my problem.

Comment: oh.. I'm actually using Unity. but your command of restarting (alt+f2, r, enter) did help me. thanks.